# Posso setar ids e classes em styles, scripts, etc?

Tags: html, html5

Posso setar `ids` e classes em `style`, `script`, etc?

Exemplo:

```
<style class="teste" id="teste">
/*
  Meu codigo aqui
*/
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes, já tinhas testado?

Exemplo em baixo.

```js
document.getElementById('teste-style').innerHTML = 'p{color: #e41;}';

document.getElementById('teste-script').innerHTML = 'alert("Foo!");';
```

```html
<style class="teste" id="teste-style">
/*
  Meu codigo aqui
*/
</style>
<script id="teste-script"></script>
<p>Texto aqui!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode. Sempre que tiver dúvida pode consultar a MDN que é considerada a documentação oficial. Lá consta todos os atributos que cada *tag* permite. No caso as duas *tags*  permitem esses atributos porque eles fazem parte do [atributos globais](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).

[Para o `<style>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).

[Para o `<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).